# TapGestureRecognizer no longer working in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

This used to work for me but no longer does. Maybe because of updates? But I am just trying to get a tap event attached to my label called JournalWarning. I was using TapGestureRecognizer.

Before I had the TapGestureRecognizer calling an OnReconnect method in xaml like so

```
<StackLayout x:Name="Journal" IsVisible="false" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="20, 0, 20, 20" Spacing="10">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label x:Name="JournalTitle" FontSize="Micro" />
            <Label x:Name="AboutFormat" Text="About Formatted Text" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="{StaticResource InputBackgroundColor}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
       </StackLayout>
       <StackLayout>
          <local:DarkKeyboardEditor x:Name="JournalContent" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:JournalTracker.Current}, Path=Content}" TextChanged="OnJournalChanged" Focused="OnEdit" Unfocused="OffEdit" FontSize="Small" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Static local:JournalTracker.Current}, Path=EntryHeight}" />
          <Label x:Name="JournalWarning" Text="Your device has lost its connection to the journal server. Journals cannot be viewed or edited at this time. Tap here to try and reconnect." FontSize="Medium" Style="{StaticResource warningLabelStyle}" IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Static local:JournalTracker.Current}, Path=IsConnected, Converter={StaticResource inverser}}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree="true">
              <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                   Tapped="OnReconnect" />
              </Label.GestureRecognizers>
         </Label>
       <BoxView x:Name="spacer" Style="{StaticResource SpacerStyle}" />
       </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

This stopped working so I thought maybe my padding was in the way and started to take away padding and margins but that made no difference so far. I also tried making the TapGestureRecognizer in C# like...

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
                OnReconnect();
            };
            JournalWarning.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

Thought about making a command instead to see if that would make a difference. I'll probably try that next idk, this seems like a really noob question and I'm not sure why this isn't getting hit at all.

Can you see anything that might be an issue? Or did something changed in an update that I missed? Thanks

Comment: What is the version of Xamarin packages you are using ?

Comment: @pac0 xamarin.forms 4.3.0.94. I updated it and VS19 this morning hoping it might solve or give me some more context to this issue, but so far it hasn't

Comment: I'm used to Xamarin features breaking on new versions. Indeed, I'd recommend you to downgrade the packages you used for a version you know it's working. For instance, due to this (probably unrelated) bug : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7327, I had to downgrade to 4.1.0.555618, and it fixed a bug I had. Do you know which version you had previously ? Did you upgrade for a particular need, or just to stay up to date ?

Comment: I upgraded just to see if this bug might go away plus just to stay up to date. I might try downgrading again here in a bit.

Comment: you might also need to try the good old "clean solution, delete obj and bin directories in all mobile projects, and rebuild all", sometimes an update doesn't get built correctly.

Comment: also, did you check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055476/tapgesturerecognizers-are-not-working?rq=1 ?

Comment: Yeah I did already, thanks. Label doesn't have a UserInteractionEnabled

Comment: @CarrO'Connor, I try to use Xamarin.Forms version 4.3.0.947036, I also have the same issue, Label's TapGestureRecognizer don't works, if I use the latest version, It works, so I think it is the bug, I suggest you can feedback this but at Github and share link here, I will also report this bug for MS,thanks.